# Вызов события абстрактного класса в наследнике

Tags: c#

Имеем абстрактный класс и событие в нем:

```
public abstract class AbstractHardwareService : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event EventHandler<DataUpdateArgs> DataUpdate;
    ....
}
```

Пытаемся вызвать это событие из класса-наследника:

```
public class SinglePhaseToGndHardwareService: AbstractHardwareService
{
     protected override void Method()
     {
          DataUpdate?.Invoke(args)
     }
}
```

Студия ругается на выражение вызова, что на событие можно только подписаться или отписаться (можно использовать только в левой части += или -=). В чем проблема?

Comment: Чтобы код заработал, добавил объявление события в класс-наследник. Но все равно интересно как наследуются события.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

События это обёртка над приватным делегатом, а приватные члены нельзя использовать в наследнике. Выход из этого следующий, делаете защищённую функцию, вызывающую событие:

```
protected void OnDataUpdate(DataUpdateArgs e)
{
    DataUpdate?.Invoke(e);
}
```

И уже в классе-наследнике вызывайте этот метод. Можно сделать её виртуальной, но не обязательно. Судя по всему, Майкрософт [рекомендуют](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x(VS.80).aspx) такие методы делать виртуальными.

Comment: Оказывается на MSDN это описано, но очень незаметно. Спасибо!

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov, если ответ Вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой.